# language in tpl output no show

Tags: php

I want to put translate word in tpl file.

languages folder
languages/english/lang.php
lang.php

```
$lang = array(

'adminpanel' => "Admin Panel",
'home' => "Home",
'database' => "Database",
);
```

function.php

```
 function lang_show($var){
    global $lang;

    if(isset($lang['$var']))
    return $lang['$var'];

}
```

index.php

```
$tpl->set('/\{lang=(.+?)\\}/ies', lang_show('\$1'));
```

And i want to output

```
{lang=home} = Home
```

But output just {lang=home}

Any suggestion? I really need

Comment: Variables is `'` quotes are not parsed.

Comment: I mean that you need to read manuals http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: any idea? I really need

Comment: Did you test your `lang_show` function?

Comment: Give me another sollution

Comment: Use `$lang[$var];` amd learn about single and double quotes

Answer (score 2):

lang.php:

```
<?php
$data['101'] = 'Admin Panel';
$data['102'] = 'Home';
$data['103'] = 'Database';
//.......
?>
```

index.php:

```
$smarty->assign('data',$data);
```

smarty file:

```
{$data.101}
```

Comment: I don't use smarty. Just .tpl and template class. I want to use lang.php file same format as my ex. in first post.

Comment: Your post is tagged with "Smarty"

Comment: any idea? I really need